# TYPO3 - Site Configuration Error #1256475113

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I've installed TYPO3 version 9.5.5 and Tool backend error when I click Site configuration ( Site Configuration -> Add new configuraton for this site).

> Error: Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1256475113: The argument "parameters" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Be\UriViewHelper". | InvalidArgumentException thrown in file /usr/share/nginx/typo3_src-9.5.5/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php in line 356.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look's like a known bug: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87573

Comment: For each exception, a documentation page is created: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/exceptions/main/en-us/Exceptions/1256475113.html. The link should usually be displayed if an exception is displayed. You can check there and also add hints yourself (use "Edit on GitHub" in top right).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an error in your site configuration file. Try to remove the complete site configuration.

Look at these locations in your installation:
/config/sites/YOUR_SITENAME/config.yaml (composer installation)
/typo3conf/sites/YOUR_SITENAME/config.yaml (non composer installation)